# need an example for better understanding

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Two matrix system:

Num1 and Num2 both have same left side(A), equal number of m and n, but the

```
b1...bm =/= 0  at least in one of them
c1...cm =/= 0  at least in one of them
```

and also at least one of the c1...cm and b1...bm is different from each other.

Num1:

```
   | b1
   | b2
 A | ...
   | bm
```

and
Num2:

```
   | c1
   | c2
 A | ...
   | cm
```

So, here's the thing: if num1 has infinity solutions, then num2 has infinity solutions. and this as I know isn't so, because there's can be contradiction at num2. But I can't think of any example of this case, can u please help me with this example?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is very unclear. I have no idea what the system you are trying to solve is, what the definition of "Num1" and "Num2" are (are they matrices?), what the factors b_i and c_i are, nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that if num1 has infinity solutions, then num2 has infinity solutions. For example, take the matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and two vectors: $$b=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, c=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

now, you can see that the system of equations $Ax=b$ has infinitely many solutions, because it can be rewritten to the system of equations $$1\cdot x_1 + 0\cdot x_2 = 1\\1\cdot x_1 + 0\cdot x_2 = 1$$

for which $x_1=1, x_2=x$ is a solution for *any* value $x\in\mathbb R$. On the other hand,  the system of equations $Ax=c$ has no solutions, as it is equal to

$$1\cdot x_1 + 0\cdot x_2 = 1\\1\cdot x_1 + 0\cdot x_2 = 0$$

and no value of $x_1$ can satisfy both equations.